# Criando bibliotecas com multiplas execuções como o Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou começando agora a desenvolver minhas próprias bibliotecas Javascript. Eu já entendo um pouco como funciona o **prototype** mas eu ainda não entendo como eu posso executar na mesma requisição mais de um método assim como o jquery faz... EX:

```
//no jquery eu posso executar qualquer função em cascata assim
$('alguma coisa').metodo1().metodo2().metodo3();

//ou assim
$('alguma coisa').metodo1();
$('alguma coisa').metodo2();
$('alguma coisa').metodo3();
```

Gostaria de saber como eu posso criar ume simples biblioteca que eu possa executar inúmeros métodos ao mesmo tempo assim como o Jquery faz...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta no final do método você retornar o próprio objeto (return this) :

Exemplo:

```
var Numero = function(num){
 this.num = num;
 this.valueOf = function(){
    return this.num;
 }
 this.maisUm = function(){
    this.num += 1;
    return this;
  }
  this.maisDois = function(){
    this.num += 2;
    return this;
  }
  return this;
}
var meuNum = new Numero(1);
alert(meuNum.maisUm().maisDois().maisUm() + 1); //1 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 6
```

Javascript é uma linguagem bem flexível, quando eu uso `Numero = function(num){ ... }` eu estou criando uma classe Numero e indicando que `function(num){...}` é seu método construtor. Dentro desse método, posso utilizar as propriedades de `this` para definir as propriedades e métodos da classe.

Comment: mas se eu fizer isso eu sou obrigado a sempre retornar o registro num, e se eu tiver mais que um elemento estruturado no this isso me quebra...

Comment: Não seja por isso, o javascript tem um método mágico chamado valueOf,  que permite que um objeto se comporte como um valor primário. 
Exemplo: 
var numDuplo = function(num){ this.num = num * 2; this.valueOf = function(){ return this.num}}

Então posso utilizar assim:

meuNumDuplo = new numDuplo(1):
alert(meuNumDuplo + 1); // retorna 3, porque o valor de meuNumDuplo será 2

Comment: @LeandroLUK E você também pode utilizar sem o "new" para ficar mais parecido com jQuery. Exemplo: Numero(3).maisUm().maisUm() + 1 //retorna 6

Comment: o que eu realmente estou procurando é gerar uma biblioteca que eu possa cruzar os métodos... entrando mais no assunto estou criando uma biblioteca para que trabalhe sobre o window.localStorage quase como se fosse SQL mesmo e por causa das variantes do SQL eu preciso poder injetar inúmeros elementos quando necessário...

Comment: Da forma que eu exemplifiquei te dá um bom norte de como fazer isso. Digamos que você quer buscar um dado do localStorage que está como jSon e pegar uma propriedade especifica dele, você poderia criar uma biblioteca que se comportasse da seguinte maneira:
localStorageLib('seuItemNoLocalStorage').get().parseJson().propriedadeQueVoceQuer.val()